# How to display data that we entered from another function in C by using struct

Tags: c, function, struct

I can't find the solution on how to view the data that we have entered before in a function that is used to enter information. Also, I'm using struct, not normal declaration and variable.

Here's the flow, I choose case 1 which will call addbook function where I will insert my data then later I will choose case 4 where the data that I just insert now supposed to be display on the screen but unfortunately it won't display the data. So, what should I do? It would be grateful if you guys could help me

*This is my coding*

```
    struct book
    {
        char title[50];
        char author[50];
        int quantity;
        int price;
    };

    struct book a;

    void addbook();
    //void searchbook();
    //void deletebook();
    void viewbook();
    //void updatebook();
    void returnfunc();



    int main()
    {
        char choice;
        do
        {
            printf("\n\n\t1.Add Book\n");
            printf("\n\t2.Search Book\n");
            printf("\n\t3.Delete Book\n");
            printf("\n\t4.View Book\n");
            printf("\n\t5.Update Book\n");
            printf("\n\t6.Exit\n");

            printf("\n\nPlease enter your choice :");
        scanf("%d",&choice);

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1 :addbook();
            break;
            //case 2 :searchbook();
            break;
            //case 3 :deletebook();
            break;
            case 4 :viewbook();
            break;
            //case 5 :updatebook();
            break;
            case 6 :printf("THANK YOU !!");
            break;

            default :printf("Wrong Choice.Please enter Again");
            break;
        }
    }
    while(choice!=6);

   return 0;
}

void addbook()
{
    printf("\n============= PLEASE ADD NEW BOOK DETAILS ================");

    int quantity;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\n\nNumber of book to insert:");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);

    struct book a[quantity];
    int i;

    fp=fopen("Bibek.dat","ab+");

    for(i=0;i<quantity;i++)
    {
        printf("Title:");
        scanf("%s", &a[i].title);

        printf("Author:");
        scanf("%s", &a[i].author);

        printf("Price:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].price);

        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n---NEW BOOK DETAILS WAS SUCCESFULLY ADDED---\n\n");

}

//void searchbook()
//{
   //printf("========SEARCH THE BOOK========");


//}

//void deletebook()
//{

//}

void viewbook(void)
{

    FILE *fp;
    int i=0,j;
    system("cls");
    printf("*********************************Book List*****************************");
    printf(" TITLE     AUTHOR       QTY     PRICE");
    j=4;
    fp=fopen("Bibek.dat","rb");
    while(fread(&a,sizeof(a),1,fp)==1)
    {
    printf("%s",a.title);
    printf("%s",a.author);
    printf("%d",a.quantity);
    printf("%d",a.price);
    printf("\n\n");
    j++;
    i=i+a.quantity;
      }
      printf("Total Books =%d",i);
      fclose(fp);

      returnfunc();
}

void returnfunc(void)
{
    {
    printf(" Press ENTER to return to main menu");
    }
    a:
    if(getch()==13) //allow only use of enter
    main();
    else
    goto a;
}

//void updatebook()
//{

//}
```

[image]

Comment: There are so many things wrong here. I don't really understand your question. What is the "struct algorithm"?

Comment: at `addbook` You forgot to write it out to a file.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so i have to make a file for addbook then?

Comment: You already did `fp=fopen("Bibek.dat","ab+");` in `addbook`. You write record by `fwrite`. (and Do `fclose` :-).

Comment: @DeiDei sorry i meant the struct data. i cant view the information i entered and i'm using struct data.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY sorry typo......so  it has to be fp=fopen("'Bibek.dat","ab+"); fwrite(str,1,sizeof(str),fp); right

Comment: `fwrite(a, sizeof(*a) , quantity, fp);` or `fwrite(a, sizeof(a) , 1, fp);`

Comment: I suggest using more systematically pointers. And write your `void display_book(struct book*b)` routine (perhaps calling it as `display_book(&a[i])` inside `addbook`)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY i tried both of it and it wont work >< maybe there is error in the viewbook function?

Comment: Don't forget to compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -g`) and to **use the debugger** (`gdb`).

Comment: @husnatasnim You are not entering `a[i].quantity`. and Did you do `fclose`?

Comment: And Delete the file before running it.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY yeah i did it, and may i know where should i add a[i].quantity ?

Comment: `printf("Quantity:"); scanf("%d", &a[i].quantity);` before `printf("Price:"); scanf("%d", &a[i].price);`. Also Change `scanf("%s", &a[i].title);...scanf("%s", &a[i].author);` to `scanf("%s", a[i].title);...scanf("%s", a[i].author);` and `char choice;` --> `int choice;`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY now i got it i overlooked most of it thank you so much!!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thank you for pointing out the routine!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changes you need are rather easy and/or in the comments. Please try it. You can modify my attempts to fix your code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct book {
    char title[50];
    char author[50];
    int quantity;
    int price;
};

struct book a;

void addbook();

//void searchbook();
//void deletebook();
void viewbook();

//void updatebook();
void returnfunc();


int main() {
    int choice;
    do {
        printf("\n\n\t1.Add Book\n");
        printf("\n\t2.Search Book\n");
        printf("\n\t3.Delete Book\n");
        printf("\n\t4.View Book\n");
        printf("\n\t5.Update Book\n");
        printf("\n\t6.Exit\n");

        printf("\n\nPlease enter your choice :");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        switch (choice) {
            case 1 :
                addbook();
                break;
                //case 2 :searchbook();
                break;
                //case 3 :deletebook();
                break;
            case 4 :
                viewbook();
                break;
                //case 5 :updatebook();
                break;
            case 6 :
                printf("THANK YOU !!");
                break;

            default :
                printf("Wrong Choice.Please enter Again");
                break;
        }
    }
    while (choice != 6);

    return 0;
}

void addbook() {
    printf("\n============= PLEASE ADD NEW BOOK DETAILS ================");

    int quantity;
    FILE *fp;

    printf("\n\nNumber of book to insert:");
    scanf("%d", &quantity);

    struct book a[quantity];
    int i;

    fp = fopen("Bibek.dat", "ab+");

    for (i = 0; i < quantity; i++) {
        printf("Title:");
        scanf("%s", a[i].title);

        printf("Author:");
        scanf("%s", a[i].author);

        printf("Price:");
        scanf("%d", &a[i].price);

        printf("\n");
    }
    fwrite(a, sizeof(a) , 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\n\n---NEW BOOK DETAILS WAS SUCCESFULLY ADDED---\n\n");
}

void viewbook(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    int i = 0, j;
    //system("cls");
    printf("*********************************Book List*****************************");
    printf(" TITLE     AUTHOR       QTY     PRICE\n");
    j = 0;
    fp = fopen("Bibek.dat", "rb");
    while (fread(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fp) == 1) {
        printf("%s ", a.title);
        printf("%s ", a.author);
        //printf("%d", a.quantity);
        printf("%d ", a.price);
        printf("\n\n");
        j++;
        i = i + a.quantity;
    }
    printf("Total Books =%d", j);
    fclose(fp);

    returnfunc();
}

void returnfunc(void) {
    printf(" Press ENTER to return to main menu");
}
```

Test

```
/a.out


    1.Add Book

    2.Search Book

    3.Delete Book

    4.View Book

    5.Update Book

    6.Exit


Please enter your choice :1

============= PLEASE ADD NEW BOOK DETAILS ================

Number of book to insert:2
Title:foo
Author:carol
Price:2

Title:bar
Author:mallory
Price:3



---NEW BOOK DETAILS WAS SUCCESFULLY ADDED---



    1.Add Book

    2.Search Book

    3.Delete Book

    4.View Book

    5.Update Book

    6.Exit


Please enter your choice :4
*********************************Book List***************************** TITLE     AUTHOR       QTY     PRICE
foo carol 2 

bar mallory 3 

Total Books =2 Press ENTER to return to main menu

    1.Add Book

    2.Search Book

    3.Delete Book

    4.View Book

    5.Update Book

    6.Exit


Please enter your choice :
```